# Derivative of a definite integral $\frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)}\int_{i=0}^{A}[x(i)]^{\alpha}di$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

Take a derivative of a definite integral $\frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)}\int_{i=0}^{A}[x(i)]^{\alpha}di$, where A is some constant.

The answer should be $\alpha[x(i)]^{\alpha - 1}$

My take (I'm not particularly good at calculus):

Rewrite $\frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)}\int_{i=0}^{A}[x(i)]^{\alpha}di$ as:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)}\int_{i=0}^{A}[x(i)]^{\alpha}dx(i)\frac{di}{dx(i)}$

Then take the derivative as follows:

$[x(i)]^{\alpha}\frac{di}{dx(i)}$

And basically I'm stuck here (told you I'm no good).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The situation is not clear to me. On the one hand $i$ is an integration variable, integrated over from 0 t0 $A$ and on the other you take the derivative wrt. $x(i)$ which depends on $i$. The answer you mention would be all right if you forget about the integration, it is just the derivative of the integrand. Please explain.

Comment: This is based on a problem from Advanced Macroeconomics by Romer. There are A types of goods with $i$ being the type of good and $x(i)$ being the respective quantities of those goods. We need to set up the Lagrangian and find the F.O.C. for $x(i)$. In order to do so, we need to take the aforementioned derivative at a sertain point. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Since you mention  a Lagrangian is it a functional derivative instead of a partial derivative?